# How to put a dashed line around a specific row in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, regex, html, css

I just found out how to display my table from PHPmyadmin but I would like the fifth row to have a dashed outline. I know how to make a dashed border in css "border-style:dashed;". The problem is how my code is calling my data from a database and putting it in a HTML table, do I need to re-code this to make the fifth row dashed?

```
// Get all the data from the "epl" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM epl") 
or die(mysql_error());  

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Pos</th> <th>Team</th> <th>PLD</th> <th>W</th> <th>D</th> 
<th>L</th> <th>F</th> <th>A</th> <th>GD</th> <th>PTS</th> </tr>";

 // keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
// Print out the contents of each row into a table
echo "<tr><td>"; 
echo $row['Pos'];
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['Team'];
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['PLD'];
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['W'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['D'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['L'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['F'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['A'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['GD'];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row['PTS'];
echo "</td></tr>"; 
}
```

An example of what I'm trying to do is on 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/tables'

Answer (score 1):

```
$count = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
   if($count == 5) {
     echo "<tr style='border-style:dashed'><td>"; 
   }
   else {
     echo "<tr><td>"; 
   }
   //other table stuff

   $count++;
}
```

Not very elegant but it should work.

Comment: I thought this was going to work but it looks like it doesn't read the statement

Comment: This helped selecting out the row but not making a dashed line around the row. Direct styling of is not allowed. You should put the border on the elements and use border-right and border-left to remove the border in between columns.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
$count = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
// Print out the contents of each row into a table
if($count === 5){
echo "<tr class=\"dashed\"><td>"; 
} else {
echo "<tr><td>"; 
}
//All others <td>
$count++;
}
```

And then create a CSS class

```
.dashed { border-bottom: 1px dashed white; }
```

Comment: You've messed up the double quotes in the class name, they either need to be escaped, or changed to single quotes.